# how to add close button to UIwebview

Tags: ios, button, webview

i create a webview and load it with a button on another view at the same ViewController.
The webview is loading a pdf file from Doc dir. Everything is working fine so far. But now the user should have a button to close the webview. How do I do this?

Thank you for your answer!

EDIT: Now I managed to add the close button. see updated code below.but if I try to close

Here is my code, that creates the webview:

```
- (IBAction)globeButton:(id)sender {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"files"];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/PDFfilename.pdf", 
                      filePathAndDirectory];

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 900, 650)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(390, 605, 160, 40);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(close:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[webView addSubview:button];}
```

But the next line results in a error: -[SecondViewController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78327c0'

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {[self.GlobeWebView removeFromSuperview];}

Answer (score 1):

Followint [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, you can either wait until the page is loaded or add the button as webView subview just after the webView is added itself. In this 'close' button action you'll want to remove the button and the web view from the superview after canceling the web vie loading.

Comment: Thank you! I added the button but I receive an error , if I click on it . See the code edit above !

Comment: @Jan because you named the method `close` and added the selector for `aMethod`, the correct way would be  [button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(close:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

Comment: thank you for this hint. I changed it, but still receiving the above mentioned error! Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Jan this can only happen if you don't have the method matching selector in the class presented by `self`. Check that you don't forget the colon if the action method has the sender argument, check the selector writing is correct, check the method is placed in the correct class.

Comment: Sorry I receive now the following error:  `-[SecondViewController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x809dbb0` I created a outlet for the webview. It seems you are right! Can you explain a little more, what to check? Sorry I am pretty new in iOS :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your **aMthod:** have any parameter? If not erase the **:** in the selector.